# Installed new python in ubuntu, can't find pip installed modules

Tags: python, ubuntu

I installed python 2.7 on ubuntu not knowing that it is already installed. I followed [this guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/101591/how-do-i-install-python-2-7-2-on-ubuntu) . It was when I couldn't import modules installed by pip that I got to know what I had done. I tried adding system path, installing module in different locations , adding to pythonpath and a few other things too.

In short I can find three installations of python2.7 in usr/local/lib, usr/local/bin and another private folder where I tried installing. The python call uses the bin installation and  pip is linked to lib installation, I tried installing request module(which I needed) in all the three paths(path/dist-utilities). Still not working.

Another thing, when I tried to see pythonpath using python

```
(os.environ['PYTHONPATH'].split(os.pathsep)), File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 23, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'PYTHONPATH'
```

is showed
Can anyone explain me what exactly happened and any solution to that and I cannot restart the server too?

@PadraicCunningham hi Padraic, which command for python shows usr/local/bin/python and same directory but pip instead of python for pip. still it shows requests not found even after pip install requests..

Comment: what does `which python` and `which pip` show from terminal also `which -a python`
?

Comment: @Liopis, how on earth would whereis python help?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I misread ...

Comment: Can you still access the Python shell? If so, do you know which Python installation it's using for that?

Comment: Have you installed it with `make install` or `make altinstall`?

Comment: @Davidmh make install -_-